# Does Crystal store any sensitive information?

Tags: crystal-lang

If a developer compiles a Crystal program, what metadata will the binary file store and how to remove any sensitive information? By sensitive I mean device identificators, local IP addresses or anything else.

Answer (score 8):

I know Crystal store basic debug information when you use:

```
crystal build myprogram.cr
```

Then you can use `--debug` flag to store all debug info (posible sensitive information as source code by example):

```
crystal build --debug myprogram.cr
```

To avoid debug info use `--no-debug` flag:

```
crystal build --no-debug myprogram.cr
```

And to optimize and obfuscate even more the binary use `--release` flag:

```
crystal build --release --no-debug myprogram.cr
```

As far I know compiled languages could store sensitive information when you compile using debug flags. The sensitive information commonly is the source code embed with the binary generated.

You can use `objdump -s --section .comment myprogram.bin` to see binary metadata like the follow:

```
.stdin:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 2028474e 55292036 2e312e31  GCC: (GNU) 6.1.1
 0010 20323031 36303830 32004743 433a2028   20160802.GCC: (
 0020 474e5529 20362e33 2e312032 30313730  GNU) 6.3.1 20170
 0030 31303900 4743433a 2028474e 55292034  109.GCC: (GNU) 4
 0040 2e372e32 20323031 32313031 35202852  .7.2 20121015 (R
 0050 65642048 61742034 2e372e32 2d352900  ed Hat 4.7.2-5).
```